# How to display the selected text value from (select drop-down) without reload the page or using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying creating a URL shortener using bootstrap-modal. I wanted to give users an option to change their domain name without hitting any button or reloading the page. so that each time user choose domain in the select tag the changes is reflected above in the (link).

The given example will help you to understand more.

**example(trying to Achieve):**https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzCK7.jpg

As you can see the domain:(http://xxxxxxx.xxx/random-code) change accordingly when user select from available domain options.

**Here is what I tried so far:**
[image: see here]

**(bootstrap - Code):**

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
       <button   type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
        Make a custom link
      </button>

     <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="display: inline-block;">Custom Link</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <p><h3 style="margin-bottom:0px;">Here you can make a custom link to send.</h3>
                                        (All custom links will stay active) </p>

                                         <p><h3 ><span style="color:#2196f3;">http://example.com/</span>AS34F49  <button style="float:;"  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Copy</button></h3>
                                         </p>
                                      <div class="form-row">

                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                          <label for="inputState">Domain:</label>
                                          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                            <option>domain1</option>
                                              <option>domain2</option>
                                                <option>domain3</option>

                                          </select>
                                        </div>

                                      </div>

                                           <div class="modal-footer">

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </form>

                       </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
```

**Problem:** I am new to jquery or javascript and I don't know the jquery behind this if anybody give some help it would be very appricheated.

Comment: "here's what I tried"...I don't see anything you tried. I see some static HTML. I don't see any attempt to write any code to meet the requirement. What did you actually try? You need to handle the "change" event of the dropdownlist, get the selected value and then use that to update the text showing the link (N.B. your span is going to need an "id" attribute so you can target it to change the value). All of that should be easy to research, even if you are very new to Javascript. It's a fairly simple, standard thing to want to do.

Comment: I try to build the structure in bootstrap. don't know jquery sir

Comment: Yes but that's just HTML. It doesn't do anything towards the bit you say is the causing the problem. As you can see, people are being kind and posting some suggestions, but really a few minutes of research and you could have discovered all of this for yourself using existing information online. It's not particularly a good use of time to repeat this kind of stuff over and over again, IMHO. If people want to do so then that's their thing but I'm just pointing out that you could actually sort this type of thing out for yourself quite easily in future.

Comment: okay sir, I guess you are right.

Comment: And If you don't know any jQuery at all then you are not really going to understand the answers you get. The first step should be to learn some jQuery / JavaScript basics so you can actually know what you're looking at.

Comment: I can understand the jquery code and add some minor modification in it. but if you say code from scratch then don't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187737/discussion-between-navjot-singh-and-adyson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Javascript `onchange()` event handler.

*Example given below.*

[Learn more Javascript Event Listeners](https://idratherbewriting.com/events-and-listeners-javascript/)

```js
function changeText(url){
  
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = url;

}
```

```html
<div id='mydiv'></div>
<select onchange='changeText(this.value)'>
  <option>http://google.com</option>
  <option>http://facebook.com</option>
  <option>http://twitter.com</option>
  <option>http://stackoverflow.com</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call a function on change of the select box which will replace the previous value with the selected value 
and give the span an id attribute as

```
<span style="color:#2196f3;" id="dynamicDomain">http://example.com/</span>
$('#inputState').change(function(){

 var domainName = $('#inputState').find(":selected").text(); //find selected text
 $('#dynamicDomain').html(domainName); //replacing it
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function DomainFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("selectDomaint").value;
  document.getElementById("showDomain").innerHTML = "Your domain: " + x;
}
```

```html
You can try like this with javascript<br>
<select id="selectDomaint" onchange="DomainFunction()">
  <option value="Abc">Abc
  <option value="Xyz">Xyz
  <option value="123">123

</select>


<p id="showDomain"></p>
```